# Groovy - count distinct with a where clause on a collection

Tags: groovy

I have the following POJO class:

```
public class MemberError{
    int lineNumber
    String type        // Can be 'A' or 'B'
    String message
}
```

There could be many errors for the same member (same lineNumber and type, different message).

Given a collection of MemberError objects, I wish to find the number of distinct members (by which I mean lineNumber) of type A and B.

The solution I have so far is this:

```
NoNullHashSet<Integer> typeAMems = errorSet.collect{ MemberError memErr ->
    if(memErr.type == 'A'){
        return memErr.lineNumber
    }
}
NoNullHashSet<Integer> typeBMems = errorSet.collect{ MemberError memErr ->
    if(memErr.type == 'B'){
        return memErr.lineNumber
    }
}
def numberOfTypeAMembersWithErrors = typeAMems.size()
def numberOfTypeBMembersWithErrors = typeBMems.size()
```

This appears to be correct but doesn't feel very neat.

Can anyone suggest another way to achieve this using the Groovy collections API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you do:

```
Set typeAMems = errorSet.findAll { it.type == 'A' }.lineNumber
Set typeBMems = errorSet.findAll { it.type == 'B' }.lineNumber
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `groupBy`

> Sorts all collection members into (sub)groups determined by the
>   supplied mapping closures.

Example:

```
def l = [new MemberError(lineNumber: 10, type: 'A', message: 'Foo'), new MemberError(lineNumber: 20, type: 'B', message: 'Bar')]

def errorsByType = l.groupBy {
    it.type
}

errorsByType.'A'.lineNumber
errorsByType.'B'.lineNumber
```

Groovy Console:

http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/2195001

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is concerned with the final count rather than intermediate data structures, consider using a nested map with default values:

```
// setup errorSet

class MemberError {
    int lineNumber
    String type        // Can be 'A' or 'B'
    String message
}

def errorSet = []
errorSet << new MemberError(lineNumber: 1, type: 'A', message: 'x')
errorSet << new MemberError(lineNumber: 1, type: 'A', message: 'y')
errorSet << new MemberError(lineNumber: 1, type: 'A', message: 'z')
errorSet << new MemberError(lineNumber: 2, type: 'A', message: 'a')
errorSet << new MemberError(lineNumber: 2, type: 'B', message: 'b')
errorSet << new MemberError(lineNumber: 2, type: 'B', message: 'c')

// simply count

def countMap = [:].withDefault { type -> 
    [:].withDefault { lineNumber -> 0 } 
}

errorSet.each { memberError ->
    countMap[memberError.type][memberError.lineNumber]++
}

// print results

countMap.each { type, map ->
    map.each { lineNumber, count ->
        println "count for { type: ${type} line: ${lineNumber} } = ${count}"
    }
}
```